# How to declare output in sql 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

@TotalRows int = NULL Output

this won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what you're doing with it. You don't need to specify a default value for an output parameter - although your client app might think it needs to supply a value. This will work:

```
create proc DoSomethingWithRows
    @TotalRows int = null output
as

set @TotalRows = 32 /*You might want to do something more imaginative than this*/
```